# Proving using number theory by: modulo? parity?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, parity

$\text{Suppose a, b and c are positive integers such that a,c are odd.}$

$\text{We are given that:} \space a^2+b^2=c^2$

$\text{Prove that b+c is a perfect square.}$

..

$\text{What I got so far:}$

$odd+even=odd \to \text{b is even}$

$(2p+1)^2+(2q)^2=(2r+1)^2$

$4p^2+4p+1+4q^2=4r^2+4r+1$

$p(p+1)+q^2=r(r+1)$

$\text{For any positive integer x,} \space x(x+1) \equiv 0 \space (mod \space 2)$

$Therefore, \space q^2 \equiv 0 \space (mod \space 2) \to q \equiv 0 \space (mod \space 2)$

$\text{I don't know what to do anymore :(}$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple

Comment: Lol that's it?!?!?! Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is false: consider the $9$, $12$, $15$ right triangle. It's true for *primitive* triples (when $b$ and $c$ are relatively prime). Then write
$$
c^2 - b^2 = a^2
$$
and factor to find a proof.

You can do this without Wikipedia's complete description of the primitive triples @labbhattacharjee points to in his comment.

Comment: I was also reading that part, thereby only stating euclid's formula for the proof would be invalid right?

Comment: Your claim follows from Euclid's formula for primitive triples but you don't need the full strength of the formula to get what you want. In fact your claim (for primitive triples) is the start of one proof of Euclid's formula (though not the proof in Wikipedia).